# Logging Microprofile fault tollerance events

Tags: quarkus, fault-tolerance, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client, smallrye

I am working on a Quarkus app that uses the smallrye microprofile fault tolerance implementation.

We have configured fault tolerance on the client definitions via the annotations API (@Retry, @Bulkhead, etc) and it seems to work but we don't get any sort of feedback about *what* is happening. Ideally we would like to get some sort of callback but even just having logs would help out in the first step.

The rest clients look something like this:

```kotlin
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "foo-backend")
@Path("/backend")
interface FooClient {

  @POST
  @Retry(maxRetries = 4, delay = 900)
  @ExponentialBackoff
  @Timeout(value = 3000)
  fun getUser(payload: GetFooUserRequest): GetFooUserResponse
}
```

Looking at the logs, even though we trace all communication, I cannot see any event even if I manually stop `foo-backend` and start it again before the retires run out.

Our logging config looks like this right now but still nothing

```
quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=request-response
quarkus.rest-client.logging.body-limit=2048
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.logging".level=DEBUG
```

Is there a way to get callbacks when a fault tolerance event happens? Or a setting which logs them out? I also would be interested in knowing when out Circuit Breakers are triggered or when a Bulkhead fills up. Logging them would be good enough for now but Ideally I would like to somehow *listen* for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable `DEBUG` logging for the `io.smallrye.faulttolerance` category, and you should get all the information you need.

Specifically for circuit breakers, you can register state change listeners for circuit breakers that have been given a name using `@CircuitBreakerName` -- just inject `CircuitBreakerMaintenance` and use `onStateChange`. See https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/5.6.0/usage/extra.html#_circuit_breaker_maintenance

There's unfortunately nothing similar for bulkheads yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can fit with your problem, but there is the FallbackHandler that can be called if any error happens. You just need to create a class to implement what you need when some fail happen and add this class in the annotation in the method that start the process.

An example you can see in the [Cookbook](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7ifxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT179&lpg=PT179&dq=RecoverHelloMessageFallback%20implements%20FallbackHandler&source=bl&ots=TkEXu6-T4u&sig=ACfU3U0L53rsi530zbMmuwyDZJVDgGw-6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAvbnpwPv9AhULfMAKHX0JCEsQ6AF6BAgZEAM#v=onepage&q=RecoverHelloMessageFallback%20implements%20FallbackHandler&f=false):

```
@Retry(maxRetries = 3,
delay = 1000)
@Fallback(RecoverHelloMessageFallback.class)
public String getHelloWithFallback() {
 failureSimulator.failAlways();
 return "hello";
}
public static class RecoverHelloMessageFallback
implements FallbackHandler<String> {
@Override
public String handle(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
 return "good bye";
}
```

[Here](https://tomee.apache.org/master/examples/mp-faulttolerance-fallback.html) you have another example. All the annotation can be combined.